# Ruby, count inside an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array of array with a string and 2 int like that :

```
[["u31", 12, 23], ["u26", 12, 23], ["u26", 11, 3]]
```

I firstly need to merge multiple occurence of these array based on the string and cumulate values of arr[1] and arr[2]

So for this exemple I need this :

```
[["u31", 12, 23], ["u26", 23, 26]]
```

Then split those both values like that :

```
[
  ["u31", "dl", 12],
  ["u31", "ul", 23],
  ["u26", "dl", 23],
  ["u31", "ul", 26]
]
```

Then sort them descending.

How can I do that ?

Comment: In the last matrix shown, do you mean to write `["u26", "ul", 26]` in the last array.

Comment: @Menelk, I'm sure you're right: an incomplete cut-paste-edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to perform the calculations in a different order:

```
arr = [["u31", 12, 23], ["u26", 12, 23], ["u26", 11, 3]]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |(s,*v),h| ['d1','ul'].zip(v).each { |t,x|
      h.update([s,t]=>x) { |_,ox,nx| ox+nx } } }.
    map { |(s,t),x| [s,t,x] }.
    sort.
    reverse
  #=> [["u31", "ul", 23],
  #    ["u31", "d1", 12],
  #    ["u26", "ul", 26],
  #    ["u26", "d1", 23]]
```

Let's see what's happening here.

```
enum0 = arr.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["u31", 12, 23], ["u26", 12, 23],
  #                  ["u26", 11, 3]]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert the enumerator to an array to see what values will be passed into the block by `each`:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[["u31", 12, 23], {}], [["u26", 12, 23], {}],
  #    [["u26", 11, 3], {}]]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to obtain each value of the enumerator and manually assign it to the block variables:

```
(s,*v),h = enum0.next
  #=> [["u31", 12, 23], {}] 
s #=> "u31" 
v #=> [12, 23] 
h #=> {}
```

Notice how I have decomposed or "disambiguated" the array that is passed to the block so that I don't have to take it apart within the block.

```
a = ['d1','ul'].zip(v)
  #=> [["d1", 12], ["ul", 23]]
```

Coming up: another enumerator:

```
enum1 = a.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["d1", 12], ["ul", 23]]:each> 
t,x = enum1.next
  #=> ["d1", 12] 
h.update([s,t]=>x)
  #=> {}.update(["u31,"d1"]=>12)
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12}
```

[Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) has a block that's used to determine the values of keys that are present in both the hash being built (`h`) and the hash being merged (`{["u31", "d1"]=>12}`). Since `h` is empty, that block is not used for the first merge.

Next,

```
t,x = enum1.next
  #=> ["ul", 23] 
h.update([s,t]=>x)
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12}.update(["u31", "ul"]=>23) 
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23}
```

where `update` returns the new value of `h`. We are finished with `enum1`, so `each` passes in the next value of `enum0` and similar calculations are performed:

```
(s,*v),h = enum0.next
  #=> [["u26", 12, 23], {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23}] 
['d1','ul'].zip(v).each { |t,x| h.update([s,t]=>x) {|_,ox,nx| ox+nx }}
  #=> [["d1", 12], ["ul", 23]]
h #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23, ["u26", "d1"]=>12,
  #    ["u26", "ul"]=>23}
```

We now pass the third and last value of `enum0` into the block. Again, the calculations are the same, except for the `update` step:

```
(s,*v),h = enum0.next
  #=> [["u26", 11, 3],
  #    {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23, ["u26", "d1"]=>12,
  #     ["u26", "ul"]=>23}]
a = ['d1','ul'].zip(v)
  #=> [["d1", 11], ["ul", 3]]
enum1 = a.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["d1", 11], ["ul", 3]]:each> 
t,x = enum1.next
  #=> ["d1", 11] 
h.update([s,t]=>x)
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23,
  #    ["u26", "d1"]=>12, ["u26", "ul"]=>23}.update(["u26","d1"],11)
  #   h and the hash being merged both have the key ["u26", "d1"], 
  #    so the merged value is determined by update's block:
  #=> { |_,ox,nx| ox+nx } => 12+11 => 23
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23,
  #    ["u26", "d1"]=>11, ["u26", "ul"]=>23} 
t,x = enum1.next
  #=> ["ul", 3] 
h.update([s,t]=>x)
  #=> {["u31", "d1"]=>12, ["u31", "ul"]=>23,
  #    ["u26", "d1"]=>11, ["u26", "ul"]=>26}
```

We are now essentially finished. We merely have to convert this hash to an array of the desired form:

```
a = h.map { |(s,t),x| [s,t,x] }
  #=> [["u31", "d1", 12], ["u31", "ul", 23],
  #    ["u26", "d1", 11], ["u26", "ul", 26]]
```

and sort:

```
a.sort.reverse
  #=> [["u31", "ul", 23],
  #    ["u31", "d1", 12],
  #    ["u26", "ul", 26],
  #    ["u26", "d1", 11]]
```